# warning in installing ruby on rails using devkit in window 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I've never used Ruby or Gems before, but to my understanding I needed to first install Ruby and a DevKit. I downloaded and installed Ruby 2.0.0-p247 (x64) and DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe, then extracted the DevKit into the Ruby folder.

I followed the instructions here, but just to keep it all in one place I'll write exactly what I did anyway...

I opened Start Command Prompt With Ruby and typed `cd C:\Ruby200-x64\devkit` and then `ruby dk.rb init` and got this:

```
Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.
```

I had a look at the file and below the comment it has - C:/Ruby200-x64 which I assume means since I haven't used anything before, there's nothing for me to modify anyway.

Now to install, I typed `ruby dk.rb install` and I was shown:

```
[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/ruby200'
[WARN] Skipping existing Devkit helper library for 'C:/ruby200'
```

and then i typed 
`gem install rails --install-dependencies --no-rdoc --no-ri`
and it returned

```
ERROR-      <invalid option > --install-dependenices
```

Comment: Do you have two Ruby installations?  One 32-bit, the other 64?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Devkit is installed properly the problem is actually that there isn't a command line option `--install-dependencies`.

Dependency installation should be automatic so `gem install rails --no-rdoc --no-ri` should accomplish the desired results.

For a list of the command line options for install run `gem help install`.